# How do I sort by human readable sizes numerically?

Tags: bash, sort

for example I have command that shows how much space folder takes

```
du folder | sort -n
```

it works great, however I would like to have human readable form

```
du -h folder
```

however if I do that than I cannot sort it as numeric.

How to join `du folder` and `du -h folder` to see output sorted as `du folder`, but with first column from `du -h folder`

P.S. this is just an example. this technique might be very useful for me (if its possible)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a more general approach. Get the output of `du folder` and `du -h folder` in two different files.

```
du folder > file1
du -h folder > file2
```

The key part is this: concatenate `file1` and `file2` line by line, with a suitable delimiter.

```
paste -d '#' file1 file2 > file3
```

(assuming `#` does not appear in `file1` and `file2`)

Now sort `file3`. Note that this will sort based on `file1` contents and break ties by `file2` contents. Extract the relevant result using `cut`:

```
sort -n -k1,7 file3 | cut -d '#' -f 2
```

Also take a look at `man sort` for other options.

---

You may also save this as an alias, for later re-use. To do so, add the following to the bottom of `~/.bashrc`:

```
sorted-du () {
    paste -d '#' <( du "$1" ) <( du -h "$1" ) | sort -n -k1,7 | cut -d '#' -f 2
}
```

Then, open a new terminal session and execute your new alias:

```
sorted-du /home
```

Comment: I added the last part on how to make your solution into an alias.

Comment: Using actual files in an alias (and then calling rm on them) is a **really really bad idea**! Think about what would happen if I actually had a file named `file3` in my directory, it would be overwritten and then deleted! @SirCharlo I am removing the alias definition from this answer and replacing it with something safer.

Comment: Well https://askubuntu.com/a/80248/22308 simply do this with `sort -h`

Answer (score 42):

Try something like:

```
du -h folder | sort -h
```

Alternatives: `-n` for Numerical sorting

Note: the `-h` option of sort only exists in newer versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: there is in version 8.17, so I guess this is the easiest way

Comment: Thanks to steabert for pointing out that the sort command has been improved from sort --version = 8.17
This is the best answer for newer versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: This should be the accepted one cause it clean-shoot that resolve the OP with `sort -h`

Answer (score 4):

This answer is valid for **10.04.4LTS** and lower versions of Ubuntu.

Unfortunatly the accurate answer which sorts K M G is difficult and complex:

You can alias the entire du command with one that sorts human readable using this

```
alias duf='du -sk * | sort -n | perl -ne '\''($s,$f)=split(m{\t});for (qw(K M G)) {if($s<1024) {printf("%.1f",$s);print "$_\t$f"; last};$s=$s/1024}'\'
```

which I found here

http://www.earthinfo.org/linux-disk-usage-sorted-by-size-and-human-readable/

just **cd** into the folder you would like to know then **duf**

you could add this duf alias to the end of your /home/user/.profile
to make the duf command semi-permenant

results:

> ```
> user@hostname:~$ duf
> 0.0K  Documenten
> 0.0K  Muziek
> 0.0K  Openbaar
> 0.0K  Sjablonen
> 0.0K  Video's
> 4.0K  backup_db.sql.g
> 4.0K  examples.desktop
> 12.0K xml printer ticket
> 52.0K hardinfo_report.html
> 152.0K    librxtxSerial.so
> 2.7M  jpos
> 4.4M  nxclient_3.5.0-7_amd64.deb
> 6.4M  nxnode_3.5.0-4_amd64.deb
> 6.8M  Downloads
> 7.4M  nxserver_3.5.0-5_amd64.deb
> 12.4M NetBeansProjects
> 18.1M mysqlworkbench.deb
> 28.3M Afbeeldingen
> 45.8M ergens-20110928-18.sql.gz
> 60.5M 2012-06-02ergens_archive.tar.gz
> 65.5M 2012-08-26ergens_archive.tar.gz
> 65.6M 2012-08-28ergens_archive.tar.gz
> 65.6M 2012-08-29ergens_archive.tar.gz
> 65.7M 2012-08-30ergens_archive.tar.gz
> 113.0M    Bureaublad
> 306.2M    ergens-20110928-18.sql
> ```

Here is why `du -sch /var/* | sort -n` does not work see the sorting of MKKMMKKMMK

> ```
> user@hostname:~$ du -sch /var/* |sort -n
>
> 0 /var/crash
> 0 /var/local
> 0 /var/lock
> 0 /var/opt
> 8,0M  /var/backups
> 12K   /var/games
> 16K   /var/tmp
> 17M   /var/log
> 68M   /var/cache
> 104K  /var/spool
> 144K  /var/run
> 351M  /var/lib
> 443M  totaal
> 704K  /var/mail
> ```

Comment: I've reported this to the gnu-core developers with a feature request to improve the du -h function with a sort feature. via bugs-coreutils@gnu.org

Comment: +1, similar one-liner: `du folder | sort -n | cut -f 2 | while IFS= read -r -d '' path; do du -sh -- "$path"; done`

Comment: Just tried your 1 liner on a live system. Get a Access Denied error and no du results. Did you try this command on an Ubuntu system first? I changed folder to /home/username

Comment: oh, sorry, you should drop the `-d ''`, that's a left-over from using it on the output of the file command.

Comment: This seems to work great on non-Linux systems which don't support GNU `sort`.

Answer (score 3):

Command GNU `sort` has the following option:

> `-h`, `--human-numeric-sort`    compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G).
>
> To have this option on BSD/OSX, you can install `sort` from `coreutils` (via `brew`) and add the bin folder to your `PATH` into your *rc* files.

So the command would looks like:

```
du -ah . | sort -rh | head -20
```

Answer (score 1):

For recent versions of Ubuntu, use `du -h directory  | sort -h` .

I use a form of this all the time for finding out-of-control files.

Comment: Duplicate of  answered Nov 17 '11 at 17:13
Allu2

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type:

```
  du -sk * | sort -rn
```

Comment: :D I am now used to changing the Ctrl+Alt+t to the format above so much so that I have pasted the required format to my Xpad.  :D Feels great to be complimented for such a menial job :)

Comment: Every work you did here worth complement.

Answer (score 0):

The one I found working on all systems regardless of the version (`sort -h` doesn't work for me) is

```
du -h $(du * | sort -n | awk '{print $2}')
```

the `awk '{print $2}'` basically prints file names.

Answer (score 0):

This one handles filenames with whitespace or apostrophes, and works on systems which do not support `xargs -d` or `sort -h`:

```
du -s * | sort -n | cut -f2 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -I {} du -sh "{}"
```

which results in:

```
368K    diskmanagementd
392K    racoon
468K    coreaudiod
472K    securityd
660K    sshd
3.6M    php-fpm
```

Comment: What's the point of replacing `\n` with `\0`? Isn't it a bit too late for that?

Comment: it prepares the input for `xargs -0`, which expects the input to be NUL delimited (as find -print0 would produce). Otherwise you can’t use -0, and apostrophes have special meaning.

Comment: I know about `-0`, but it's irrelevant: http://imgur.com/87w3vfj

Comment: I think that is working as you have used a backtick, not an apostrophe. https://gist.github.com/mrmanc/8aef830945ce03aa65f0