# finding some files and sorting the result by size and copy it to folder

Tags: find

well I want to use the cmd "find" to search some files and in the same time I want to sort the result by size

```
sudo find ~ -name $i -exec du -sh {} \; | sort -nr | head -1
```

I used the cmd "du" for the sizes and "sort" to sort the sizes from the highest to the lowest but it doesn't work, can someone help me please.

And I want at the end to copy the result of my research to a folder so I used :

```
cp ` find ~ -type f -name $i -exec du -sk {} \; | sort -nr | head -1 ` The_Directory
```

So this one I used, is to copy the file with the highest size but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. When you say "it doesn't work" what happens rather than it copying the file you want it to copy. Because of the $i I assume you have put these commands in a file and are executing them as part of, or all of, a shell script. Is that the case?

Comment: One issue is that if you use `du -h` you should probably also be using `sort -h` (a plain numeric sort won't handle the `K,M,G` filesize multipliers properly).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort by human readable sizes numerically?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/80244/how-do-i-sort-by-human-readable-sizes-numerically)

Comment: You will also need to cut the size field from the output before passing the output to the copy command.

Answer (score 0):

`du -h` reports human readable size suffixes (K,M,G), but to sort you need all fixes to be reported using a common size suffix:

```
find ~ -name "$i" -exec du -sk {} \;|sort -rn
```

To extract the largest:

```
x=$(find . -name "$i" -exec du -sk {} \;|sort -rn|head -1|sed -e's:[0-9]*::')
cp "$x" ...
```